# Extracting text from a .tex document with Python regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, latex

I'm attemping to retrieve a bunch a text from a LaTeX file, that consists of blocks like

```
\newcommand{\lhaac}{% 2
Olkoot tapahtumat A = 'kortti on musta', B = 'kortti on hertta' ja 
C = 'kortti on kuvakortti tai ässä'. Lausu seuraavat tapahtumat joukkojen A,B ja C sekä joukko-operaatioiden avulla\\% ja laske todennäköisyydet  \\
        \textbf{a)}     Kortti on musta kuvakortti tai musta ässä\\
        \textbf{b)} Kortti on ruutu\\
        \textbf{c)} Kortti ei ole ruutu, mutta se on kuva tai ässä\\
        \textbf{d)} Kortti on joko punainen tai se on arvoltaan 2-10, mutta ei molempia

}
%__________
\newcommand{\lhaacv}{%
a) Kortti on musta kuvakortti tai musta ässä = Kortti on musta ja kortti on kuvakortti tai  ässä: $A\cap C$,\\  
b) Kortti on ruutu = kortti ei musta ja ei hertta: $\overline{A}\cap\overline{B} = \overline{A\cup B}$\\
c) (Kortti on musta tai hertta) ja kortti on  kuva tai ässä:\\ $(A\cup B)\cap C = (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)$ \\ 
d) Kortti on punainen kuvakortti tai musta pikkukortti:\\ $(\overline{A}\cap C)\cup (A\cap \overline{C}) = (\overline{A}\cup \overline{C})\backslash (\overline{A}\cap \overline{C})$

}
```

Using `re.findall`, I would like to gain access to the 3-letter code immediately succeeding `\lh` in each command, and the command contents or definitions, meaning the  entire blocks of text contained between the braces after the command name definition.

Parsing the  3-letter code is not an issue, but simply gaining access to all of the contents of `\newcommand{\lhaac}{<contents>}` is proving to be difficult, since LaTeX source can contain braces and backslashes and other nasty things, making it difficult to express how contents I want to access actually end (because a brace ends a command definition). The comment lines

```
%__________
```

can not be trusted to exist after every command.

I've tried [this](https://regex101.com/r/OWVJSw/4) and [this](https://regex101.com/r/OWVJSw/5), for starters. In the first case, the matching stops after the first `}` encountered, while in the second example pretty much everything after the beginning `{` is matched, just as expected. Attempting something more complicated like [this](https://regex101.com/r/OWVJSw/2) seems to work on a simple test case, but [entering an actual block found in the file](https://regex101.com/r/OWVJSw/6) produces no match.

I'm therefore asking for help in cracking this puzzle. I can't seem to see what I'm missing here. In the last case, I think I've covered normal text, math (both inline `$<math here>$` and display `$$<math here>$$`), and commands (`\<command name>[<optional argument>]{<mandatory argument>}`) with and without arguments. Environments, such as

```
\begin{<environment name>}[<optional argument>]{<mandatory argument>}
  <contents>
\end{<environment name>}
```

are still missing, but those can be easily covered later.

As per [`re.findall` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), it should return a list of tuples (since I have multiple capturing groups in the regex), with the 3-letter code as the first and the command contents as the second element of each tuple. In this case the first tuple (contained in a list) returned would be

```
[("aac", "% 2
Olkoot tapahtumat A = 'kortti on musta', B = 'kortti on hertta' ja 
C = 'kortti on kuvakortti tai ässä'. Lausu seuraavat tapahtumat joukkojen A,B ja C sekä joukko-operaatioiden avulla\\% ja laske todennäköisyydet  \\
        \textbf{a)}     Kortti on musta kuvakortti tai musta ässä\\
        \textbf{b)} Kortti on ruutu\\
        \textbf{c)} Kortti ei ole ruutu, mutta se on kuva tai ässä\\
        \textbf{d)} Kortti on joko punainen tai se on arvoltaan 2-10, mutta ei molempia

")]
```

Comment: post expected output for example

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Done. Example added.

Comment: You could use PyPi regex module and use [this code](https://rextester.com/RADV75987)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You go:

=^..^=

```
import re

raw_string = """\newcommand{\lhaac}{% 2
Olkoot tapahtumat A = 'kortti on musta', B = 'kortti on hertta' ja 
C = 'kortti on kuvakortti tai ässä'. Lausu seuraavat tapahtumat joukkojen A,B ja C sekä joukko-operaatioiden avulla\\% ja laske todennäköisyydet  \\
        \textbf{a)}     Kortti on musta kuvakortti tai musta ässä\\
        \textbf{b)} Kortti on ruutu\\
        \textbf{c)} Kortti ei ole ruutu, mutta se on kuva tai ässä\\
        \textbf{d)} Kortti on joko punainen tai se on arvoltaan 2-10, mutta ei molempia

}
%__________
\newcommand{\lhaacv}{%
a) Kortti on musta kuvakortti tai musta ässä = Kortti on musta ja kortti on kuvakortti tai  ässä: $A\cap C$,\\  
b) Kortti on ruutu = kortti ei musta ja ei hertta: $\overline{A}\cap\overline{B} = \overline{A\cup B}$\\
c) (Kortti on musta tai hertta) ja kortti on  kuva tai ässä:\\ $(A\cup B)\cap C = (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)$ \\ 
d) Kortti on punainen kuvakortti tai musta pikkukortti:\\ $(\overline{A}\cap C)\cup (A\cap \overline{C}) = (\overline{A}\cup \overline{C})\backslash (\overline{A}\cap \overline{C})$

}
%__________
"""

remove_command = re.sub(r'\newcommand{\\', '', raw_string)
codes = re.findall('lh\w+', remove_command)

part_1 = []
for item in codes:
    part_1.append(item[2::])


result2 = re.findall(r'{.*?}\n%_+', remove_command, re.DOTALL)
part_2 = []
for item in result2:
    clean_1 = re.sub(r'{%', '', item)
    clean_2 = re.sub(r'\n}\n%_+', '', clean_1)
    part_2.append(clean_2)


result = zip(part_1, part_2)
```

Output:

```
aac
 2
Olkoot tapahtumat A = 'kortti on musta', B = 'kortti on hertta' ja 
C = 'kortti on kuvakortti tai ässä'. Lausu seuraavat tapahtumat joukkojen A,B ja C sekä joukko-operaatioiden avulla\% ja laske todennäköisyydet  \
            extbf{a)}     Kortti on musta kuvakortti tai musta ässä\
            extbf{b)} Kortti on ruutu\
            extbf{c)} Kortti ei ole ruutu, mutta se on kuva tai ässä\
            extbf{d)} Kortti on joko punainen tai se on arvoltaan 2-10, mutta ei molempia

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
aacv

a) Kortti on musta kuvakortti tai musta ässä = Kortti on musta ja kortti on kuvakortti tai  ässä: $A\cap C$,\  
b) Kortti on ruutu = kortti ei musta ja ei hertta: $\overline{A}\cap\overline{B} = \overline{A\cup B}$\
c) (Kortti on musta tai hertta) ja kortti on  kuva tai ässä:\ $(A\cup B)\cap C = (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)$ \ 
d) Kortti on punainen kuvakortti tai musta pikkukortti:\ $(\overline{A}\cap C)\cup (A\cap \overline{C}) = (\overline{A}\cup \overline{C}ackslash (\overline{A}\cap \overline{C})$
```

Comment: Once again, `re.DOTALL` comes to the rescue.